# Prefixe pluri- suivi d’un radical commençant par la lettre i

Tags: orthographe, néologismes, préfixes, trait-d-union

Je cherche à écrire le mot *pluri-individuel* qui est formé du radical *individuel* augmenté du préfixe *[pluri-](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pluri-)*. Cependant, je ne sais pas si pour des raisons d’euphonie, l’un des deux *i* doit s’élider ou si un trait d’union doit être maintenu.

Donc, laquelle des propositions suivantes est la plus exacte (et pourquoi ?) :

1. plur**i**ndividuel (élision d’un *i*)
2. plur**i-i**ndividuel (introduction d’un trait d’union séparant le préfixe du radical)
3. plur**ii**ndividuel (maintiens des deux *i* O.ô)

Comment: Ne dit-on pas simplement : "Pluriel" ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Il est clair que votre première proposition, « plurindividuel », qui se lirait *\plyʁɛ̃dividɥɛl\* et non *\plyʁiɛ̃dividɥɛl\*, est incorrecte.

Par ailleurs, le [Dictionnaire de l'Académie française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pluri-) et l'[office québécois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1676) recommandent de **souder le préfixe « pluri- » au mot qu'il modifie**, sans autre forme de jugement, sans doute du fait de la relative rareté du préfixe.

> **Prononc. et Orth.:** [plyʀi-]. Mots constr. soudés.

> Les mots formés avec le préfixe *pluri-* ne prennent pas de trait d'union. Le second élément se lie directement au préfixe.

Toutefois, il me semble pertinent de **le rapprocher du préfixe « multi- »**, de sens proche (contrairement à « omni- »), avec autant de syllabes (contrairement à « di- » et « tri- ») et se terminant par la même lettre. Puisqu'il est plus prolifique, l'[office québécois de la langue française](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=1533) précise la nécessité d'ajouter un trait d'union lorsque le radical commence par un I.

> Les mots formés avec le préfixe *multi-* ne prennent pas de trait d'union. Le second élément se lie directement au préfixe, sauf lorsque cet élément commence par la voyelle *i*.

Par conséquent, il me semble que **l'orthographe correcte est « pluri-individuel »**.